# Need query for this output

Tags: mysql

Need sql query for this output:

if location = 'chennai' then,

```
A       2
B       1
```

This is my table structure :

```
location               team

chennai                 A
Bangalore               A
Bangalore               B
chennai                 B
madurai                 B
chennai                 A
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select team,count(team) from tb_name where location='chennai' group by team
```